# Apache Beam GCP upload Avro in dynamically created directories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pipeline, dataflow, apache-beam

I want to make a streaming Apache Beam pipeline in GCP which reads data from Google Pub/Sub and push it to GCS. I have the bit where I can read the data from Pub/Sub. 
My current code looks like that (picked it up from one of GCP Apache beam templates)

```
pipeline.apply("Read PubSub Events",
  PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
                .apply("Map to Archive", ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageToArchiveDoFn()))
                .apply(
                        options.getWindowDuration() + " Window",
                        Window.into(FixedWindows.of(DurationUtils.parseDuration(options.getWindowDuration()))))
                .apply(
                        "Write File(s)",
                        AvroIO.write(AdEvent.class)
                                .to(
                                        new WindowedFilenamePolicy(
                                                options.getOutputDirectory(),
                                                options.getOutputFilenamePrefix(),
                                                options.getOutputShardTemplate(),
                                                options.getOutputFilenameSuffix()))
                                .withTempDirectory(NestedValueProvider.of(
                                        options.getAvroTempDirectory(),
                                        (SerializableFunction<String, ResourceId>) input ->
                                                FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(input)))
                                .withWindowedWrites()
                                .withNumShards(options.getNumShards()));
```

It can produce files which look like this 
`windowed-file2020-04-28T09:00:00.000Z-2020-04-28T09:02:00.000Z-pane-0-last-00-of-01.avro`

I want to store the data in GCS in dynamically created directories. In the following directories `2020-04-28/01`, `2020-04-28/02`, etc - the `01` and `02` are subdirectories denoting the hour of the day when the data got processed by the dataflow streaming pipeline.

Example:

```
gs://data/2020-04-28/01/0000000.avro
gs://data/2020-04-28/01/0000001.avro
gs://data/2020-04-28/01/....

gs://data/2020-04-28/02/0000000.avro
gs://data/2020-04-28/02/0000001.avro
gs://data/2020-04-28/02/....

gs://data/2020-04-28/03/0000000.avro
gs://data/2020-04-28/03/0000001.avro
gs://data/2020-04-28/03/....
...
```

The 0000000, 0000001, etc are simple file names which I have used for illustration, I do not expect the files to be sequentially names.
Do you think this is possible in a GCP dataflow streaming setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own [FilenamePolicy](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.java#L357-L392) (perhaps using `WindowedFilenamePolicy` as a starting point) to use your own logic for defining output paths. You can use `/` characters in your file paths as you wish (by the way, GCS buckets are ["flat"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork), they don't really have directories). To get the dates/times, the `windowedFilename` method takes the window information as an argument, so you can use that in your return value however you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `writeDynamic` instead of `Write`. Unfortunately, the AvroIO doesnt support writeDynamic natively as mentioned [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.Write.html#to-org.apache.beam.sdk.io.DynamicAvroDestinations-) and instead you would need to use a FileIO.

Below is a sample implementation in Scala using Scio

```
    val dynamicOutput: FileIO.Write[String, GenericRecord] = FileIO
      .writeDynamic[String, GenericRecord]()
      .by((input: GenericRecord) => {
        input.get("id").toString.toUpperCase  + "/"
      })
      .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
      .withNumShards(1) // Since input is small, restrict to one file per bucket
      .withNaming(
        new SerializableFunction[String, FileNaming] {
          override def apply(partitionCol: String): FileNaming = {
            FileIO.Write.defaultNaming(s"Id=$partitionCol", ".parquet")
          }
        }
      )
      .via(Contextful.fn[GenericRecord,GenericRecord](
          new SerializableFunction[GenericRecord,GenericRecord]{
            override def apply(input: GenericRecord): GenericRecord = {
              val r = new GenericData.Record(outputSchema)
              r.put("amount",input.get("amount"))
              r.put("name",input.get("name"))
              r.put("type",input.get("type"))
              r
            }
          }
        ),
        ParquetIO.sink(outputSchema)
      )
      .to("gs://bucket-name/table-name")
```

In the above example I am using GenericRecord type and specifying a schema and creating dynamic partitions and writing the file in Parquet format. You can choose to write the data in any format.

Comment: Interesting, let me check this out. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Jayadeep With this approach how would you handle the skewed data and small file problem (is there any way to specify file roll over policy based on size)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pub/Sub to Cloud Storage Avro template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#pubsub-to-cloud-storage-avro) is a streaming pipeline that reads data from a Pub/Sub topic and writes Avro files into the specified Cloud Storage bucket. This pipeline supports optional user provided window duration to be used to perform windowed writes.

Comment: So I actually got the code for that template for github and it seems to partially work, but I keep on running into this error in dataflow - "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GCS object names must not contain Carriage Return or Line Feed characters."

Comment: --stagingLocation=gs://test/dataflow/pipelines/staging/ \
   --tempLocation=gs://test/dataflow/pipelines/temp/ \
   --runner=DataflowRunner \
   --windowDuration=1m \
   --numShards=1 \
   --inputTopic=projects/test/topics/testTopic \
   --outputDirectory=gs://test/output/YYYY/MM/DD/ \
   --outputFilenameSuffix=.avro
   --avroTempDirectory=gs://test/avro-temp-dir/ \
   --outputShardTemplate=-SSS-NNN"

Comment: These are the args that I am using to pass to the job to run ^^